# Legacy IzPack in ant issue

Tags: java, ant, legacy, izpack

I have an old ant script I am trying to run to create an installer for some legacy software.

The check for whether IzPack is installed is failing, even though I have installed IzPack 5.0

Here is the ant file segment for that check:

```
  <target name="check-izpack" depends="init-build">
    <available property="izpack.present"
               classname="com.izforge.izpack.ant.IzPackTask"
               classpathref="installer.cp" />
    <fail unless="izpack.present">.

       The IzPack program is not available.  Download it from
       http://www.izforge.com/izpack/.  Install it, and set the
       'izpack.home' property in your local build.properties.
    </fail>
    <taskdef name="izpack" classname="com.izforge.izpack.ant.IzPackTask"
             classpathref="installer.cp"/>
  </target>
```

And further down:

```
  <path id="installer.cp">
    <path refid="classpath" />
    <pathelement location="${izpack.home}/lib/standalone-compiler.jar"/>
  </path>
```

`izpack.home` is set to the appropriate location in my build.properties file.  But I notice that in the `/lib` directory, there is no jarfile named `standalone-compiler.jar` which I understand was something from older versions of IzPack.

Is there a way I can make this work?  (Preferably without me needing to learn all about IzPack and ant.) If I can get my hands on an appropriate legacy version of IzPack would that be the easiest way to go?  Or is there an easy conversion for the new IzPack that might work for me?

Answer (score 1):

In Izpack 5.0 they split the single standalone jar to multiple jars. From looking at the latest version on [Github](https://github.com/izpack/izpack) it seems the class is now in izpack-ant jar.

Try changing the class path jar to izpack-ant that should exist in the folder instead of the standalone jar.

Comment: The actual file in my library is izpack-ant-5.0.0-rc5.jar -- should I specify it by name and version like that, or is it smart enough to deal with different versions?

Comment: You will need to specify the full name. Forgot to mention it. You can also rename the file and remove the version, however I don't recommend it.

Comment: Please post the error you get. Maybe the jar depends on other jars which causes the problem.

Comment: The error I get is the "fail" message from the build.xml file:
    The IzPack program is not available.  Download it from
       http://www.izforge.com/izpack/.  Install it, and set the
       'izpack.home' property in your local build.properties.

Comment: Maybe try searching for the class name in the jar. The file might be corrupted. In addition please make sure the izpack.home points to the right folder by trying to print out the value in the ant file using echo task

Comment: I did the echo thing for izpack.home.  I even moved IzPack to a directory that doesn't have spaces in the path, and tried all 3 of `C:\IzPack`, `C:/IzPack` and `/cygdrive/c/IzPack` in case that mattered. (I am running from cygwin on a Windows machine)  Previously the path was set to `C:/Program Files/IzPack` which worked with the older version of IzPack which had been installed on an older machine in that location.  I'll try seeing if the file is in the jar.

Comment: Standalone compiler support was dropped in v5. Correct way is to use izpack-maven-plugin, is there any particular reason why you insist on ant?